# How can I extract a URL from a sentence that is in a NSString?

Tags: ios, regex, cocoa-touch, nsstring

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows. I have a NSString with a sentence that has a URL within the sentience. I'm needing to be able to grab the URL that is presented within any sentence that is within a NSString so for example:

Let's say I had this NSString

```
NSString *someString = @"This is a sample of a http://example.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
```

I need to be able to extract http://example.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA from within that NSString. This NSString isn't static and will be changing structure and the url will not necessarily be in the same spot of the sentence. I've tried to look into the three20 code but it makes no sense to me. How else can this be done?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25574255/1966109) for a similar question that uses Swift 3  and gives 2 ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you should probably use `NSDataDetector` as Dave mentions. Far less prone to error than regular expressions.

---

Take a look at [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions). You can construct a simple one to extract the URL using the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) class, or find one online that you can use. For a tutorial on using the class, see [here](http://cocoabyss.com/2010/first-step-with-nsregularexpression/).

---

The code you want essentially looks like this (using John Gruber's [super URL regex](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)):

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *someString = @"This is a sample of a http://example.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];
NSLog(@"%@", match); // Correctly prints 'http://example.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA'
```

That will extract the first URL in any string (of course, this does no error checking, so if the string really doesn't  contain any URL's it won't work, but take a look at the `NSRegularExpression` class to see how to get around it.

Answer (score 92):

Use an [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector):

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://example.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
    NSURL *url = [match URL];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to rely on an unreliable regular expression, and as Apple upgrades their link detection code, you get those improvements for free.

Comment: +1 Awesome!!! I didn't know their was a link detection code for NSDataDetector. Well, I just learned something new. Thanks Dave, I'll have to test both the regular expression and your NSDataDector code out to see which best fit's my needs. However, I'm with you on about rather using Apple's code rather than unreliable code. Thanks Again. I just might have to change my Answer. :-)

Comment: @0SX you're welcome.  Just a caveat: this only works on iOS 4+

Comment: Really Awesome +1 for you bro ... (Dave Delong)
Thankyou Very much for the code explanation :)

Comment: Thx Dave. How would you extract that link? Is using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString the best way?

Comment: @marciokoko `NSTextCheckingResult` can tell you the range of the matching substring, which you can then use with `substringWithRange:`

Comment: +1, but why am I getting an implicit conversion type warning? It says I am converting an NSTextCheckingType enum to a NSTextCheckingTypes enum. What's that about?

Comment: Awesome! I'd like to +100000

Answer (score 5):

**Use Like This:**

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                                                           error:&error];

[detector enumerateMatchesInString:someString
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, someString.length)
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
     {
         NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result.URL];
         NSLOG(%@,str);

     }
 }];
```

This will Output the all links in your someString one by one

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
NSURL *url;
NSArray *listItems = [someString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for(int i=0;i<[listItems count];i++)
{
    NSString *str=[listItems objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([str rangeOfString:@"http://"].location == NSNotFound)
        NSLog(@"Not url");
    else 
        url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your code, this actually works also but in an array format which could be useful for some things :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2 :

```
let input = "This is a test with the URL https://www.hackingwithswift.com to be detected."
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))

for match in matches {
    let url = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)
    print(url)
}
```

[Source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-detect-a-url-in-a-string-using-nsdatadetector)

Comment: Erroneous downvote here. please someone up-vote it back! It works!

Answer (score 2):

you need two things:

1. A category that adds regex to NSString (i.e. RegexKit)
2. [Matching Regex for URLS](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

regards,

Comment: @0SX, be sure to use REGEX and gruber's matching schema for Urls. That's the best way to obtain the the URL substring.

Answer (score 2):

Funny you mention three20, that was the first place I was going to go look for the answer. Here's the method from three20:

```
- (void)parseURLs:(NSString*)string {
    NSInteger index = 0;
    while (index < string.length) {
        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(index, string.length - index);
        NSRange startRange = [string rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                             range:searchRange];
        if (startRange.location == NSNotFound) {
            NSString* text = [string substringWithRange:searchRange];
            TTStyledTextNode* node = [[[TTStyledTextNode alloc] initWithText:text] autorelease];
            [self addNode:node];
            break;
        } else {
            NSRange beforeRange = NSMakeRange(searchRange.location, startRange.location - searchRange.location);
            if (beforeRange.length) {
                NSString* text = [string substringWithRange:beforeRange];
                TTStyledTextNode* node = [[[TTStyledTextNode alloc] initWithText:text] autorelease];
                [self addNode:node];
            }

            NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(startRange.location, string.length - startRange.location);
            NSRange endRange = [string rangeOfString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                             range:searchRange];
            if (endRange.location == NSNotFound) {
                NSString* URL = [string substringWithRange:searchRange];
                TTStyledLinkNode* node = [[[TTStyledLinkNode alloc] initWithText:URL] autorelease];
                node.URL = URL;
                [self addNode:node];
                break;
            } else {
                NSRange URLRange = NSMakeRange(startRange.location,
                                         endRange.location - startRange.location);
                NSString* URL = [string substringWithRange:URLRange];
                TTStyledLinkNode* node = [[[TTStyledLinkNode alloc] initWithText:URL] autorelease];
                node.URL = URL;
                [self addNode:node];
                index = endRange.location;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time it does `[self addNode:node];` after the first `if` part, it's adding a found URL. This should get you started! Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Of course, if compiling for the iPhone, there's no reason to use convoluted code like this instead of the `NSRegularExpression` class.

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift 2.2 - NSDataDetector

```
let string = "here is the link www.google.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = [ .Link]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
detector?.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (string as NSString).length)) { (result, flags, _) in
    if(result?.URL != nil){
        print(result?.URL)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this answer, I've tested again and it is working perfectly!!!!!

Comment: I downvoted this and then found an error in my source data. This works, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.x 
Xcode 12.x

```
let string = "This is a test with the URL https://www.hackingwithswift.com to be detected. www.example.com"
let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [ .link]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
detector?.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (string as NSString).length)) { (result, flags, _) in
    if(result?.url != nil){
        print(result?.url)
    }
}
```