# NSRegularExpression to validate URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I found this regular expression on a website. It is said to be the best URL validation expression out there and I agree. Diego Perini created it.

The problem I am facing is when trying to use it with `objective-C` to detect URLs on strings. I have tried using options like `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines`, `NSRegularExpressionIgnoreMetacharacters` and others, but still no luck.

Is the expression not well formatted for `Objective-C`? Am I missing something? Any ideas?

I have tried John Gruber's regex, also, but it fails with some invalid URLs.

```
        Regular Expression                                  Explanation of expression                      

 ^                                                  match at the beginning
//Protocol identifier
(?:
    (?:https?|ftp                                   http, https or ftp
    ):\\/\\/                                        ://
)?                                                  optional
// User:Pass authentication
(?:
    ^\\s+                                           non white spaces, 1 or more times
    (?:
        :^\\s*                                      : non white spaces, 0 or more times, optionally
    )?@                                             @
)?                                                  optional
//Private IP Addresses                              ?! Means DO NOT MATCH ahead. So do not match any of the following
(?:
    (?!10                                           10                                                          10.0.0.0 - 10.999.999.999
        (?:
            \\.\\d{1,3}                             . 1 to 3 digits, three times
        ){3}
    )
    (?!127                                          127                                                         127.0.0.0 - 127.999.999.999
        (?:
            \\.\\d{1,3}                             . 1 to 3 digits, three times
        ){3}
    )
    (?!169\\.254                                    169.254                                                     169.254.0.0 - 169.254.999.999
        (?:
            \\.\\d{1,3}                             . 1 to 3 digits, two times
        ){2}
    )
    (?!192\\.168                                    192.168                                                     192.168.0.0 - 192.168.999.999
        (?:
            \\.\\d{1,3}                             . 1 to 3 digits, two times
        ){2}
    )
    (?!172\\.                                       172.                                                        172.16.0.0 - 172.31.999.999
        (?:                                                                                                             
            1[6-9]                                  1 followed by any number between 6 and 9
            |                                       or
            2\\d                                    2 and any digit
            |                                       or
            3[0-1]                                  3 followed by a 0 or 1
        )
        (?:
            \\.\\d{1,3}                             . 1 to 3 digits, two times
        ){2}
    )
    //First Octet IPv4                              // match these. Any non network or broadcast IPv4 address
    (?:
        [1-9]\\d?                                   any number from 1 to 9 followed by an optional digit        1 - 99
        |                                           or
        1\\d\\d                                     1 followed by any two digits                                100 - 199
        |                                           or
        2[01]\\d                                    2 followed by any 0 or 1, followed by a digit               200 - 219
        |                                           or
        22[0-3]                                     22 followed by any number between 0 and 3                   220 - 223
    )
    //Second and Third Octet IPv4
    (?:
        \\.                                         .
        (?:
            1?\\d{1,2}                              optional 1 followed by any 1 or two digits                  0 - 199
            |                                       or
            2[0-4]\\d                               2 followed by any number between 0 and 4, and any digit     200 - 249
            |                                       or
            25[0-5]                                 25 followed by any numbers between 0 and 5                  250 - 255
        )
    ){2}                                            two times
    //Fourth Octet IPv4
    (?:
        \\.                                         .
        (?:
            [1-9]\\d?                               any number between 1 and 9 followed by an optional digit    1 - 99
            |                                       or
            1\\d\\d                                 1 followed by any two digits                                100 - 199
            |                                       or
            2[0-4]\\d                               2 followed by any number between 0 and 4, and any digit     200 - 249
            |                                       or
            25[0-4]                                 25 followed by any number between 0 and 4                   250 - 254
        )
    )
    //Host name
    |                                               or                  
    (?:
        (?:
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?                any letter, digit or character one or more times with optional -
        )*                                          zero or more times
        [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+                      any letter, digit or character one or more times
    )
    //Domain name
    (?:
        \\.                                         .
        (?:
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?                any letter, digit or character one or more times with optional -
        )*                                          zero or more times
        [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+                      any letter, digit or character one or more times
    )*                                              zero or more times
    //TLD identifier
    (?:
        \\.                                         .
        (?:
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}                  any letter, digit or character more than two times
        )
    )
)
//Port number
(?:
    :\\d{2,5}                                       : followed by any digit, two to five times, optionally
)?              
//Resource path
(?:
    \\/[^\\s]*                                      / followed by an optional non space character, zero or more times
)?                                                  optional
$                                                  match at the end
```

**EDIT** 
I think I forgot to say that I am using the expression in the following code: (partial code)

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *detector = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[self theRegularExpression] options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *links = [detector matchesInString:theText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, theText.length)];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^(?i)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?$
```

Is the best URL validation regular expression I found and it is explained on my question. It is already formatted to work on Objective-C. However, using it with `NSRegularExpression` gave me all sorts of problems, including my app crashing. `RegexKitLite` had no problems handling it. I do not know if it is a size limitation or some flag not being set.
My final code looked like:

```
//First I take the string and put every word in an array, then I match every word with the regular expression
NSArray *splitIntoWordsArray = [textToMatch componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewLineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableString *htmlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textToMatch];
for (NSString *theText in splitIntoWordsArray){
    NSEnumerator *matchEnumerator = [theText matchEnumeratorWithRegex:theRegularExpressionString];
    for (NSString *temp in matchEnumerator){
        [htmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:temp withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>", temp, temp] options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])];
    }
}
[htmlString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, htmlString.length)];
//embed the text on a webView as HTML
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, [mainFont fontName], [mainFont pointSize], htmlString] baseURL:nil];
```

The result: a `UIWebView` with some embedded HTML, where URLs and emails are clickable. Do not forget to set `dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone`

You can also try

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)(?:(?:https?):\\/\\/)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"error");
NSString *someString = @"This is a sample of a sentence with a URL http://. http://.. http://../ http://? http://?? http://??/ http://# http://-error-.invalid/ http://-.~_!$&'()*+,;=:%40:80%2f::::::@example.com within it.";
NSRange range = [expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])];
if (!NSEqualRanges(range, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))){
    NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", match);
}   
else {
    NSLog(@"no match");
}
```

Hope it helps somebody in the future

The regular expression will sometimes cause the application to hang, so I decided to use gruber's regular expression modified to recognize url without protocol or the www part:

```
(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))*(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’])*)
```

Comment: Your updated gruber code is good, however it does not match "google.com" - it does, however match "google.comm" and "google.co.uk" - any idea how to tweak that?

Comment: Dude many thanks for the regular expression. Its really amazing.

Answer (score 7):

> Am I missing something?

You're missing the built-in stuff to do this for you.  There's a handy object called [`NSDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You create it to look for certain data "types" (like, say, [`NSTextCheckingTypeLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextCheckingTypeLink)), then ask it for its [`-matchesInString:options:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW6).

[Here's an earlier answer of mine showing how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590440/how-can-i-extract-a-url-from-a-sentence-that-is-in-a-nsstring/4590734#4590734).

Comment: Thank you Dave for your quick answer. I have tried it before, but it does not recognize some URLs, like the .asia, .info, etc. That is when the URL is not well-formed like http://healthyhomes.asia This is why I am using a regular expression. Using an online tester, it detects healthyhomes.asia or info.info withour the protocol part.

Comment: 2017 update: just checked NSDataDetector. `info.info` now works, but `healthyhomes.asia` still doesn't. `www.google.c` DOES work. No idea how Safari (iOS & desktop) can visit `healthyhomes.asia` if `Foundation`'s `NSDataDetector` doesn't support such a URL.