# Gruber URL Regex tweak to capture "domain.com"

Tags: regex, url

I found an updated version of John Gruber's regex for url matching [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738521/nsregularexpression-to-validate-url) by user [GianPac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202169/gianpac), which states it's been adapted to recognize url without protocol or the www part:

(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)(?:[^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+)))))(?:(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+))))|[^\s`!()[]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))

Whilst this works in most cases, I found it does not match **"google.com"**. It does match **"google.comm"** and **"google.co.uk"**, so this must be a small oversight.

The trouble is, I literally hate regex. It's the bane of my life. I just want to try and tweak this one more time to allow for "google.com" - can anyone throw me a pointer? I (think) it's something to do with this part of the code:

```
+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from {2,4} to {1,4} and it will match.

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.-]+[.][a-z]{1,4}/?)(?:[^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+)))))(?:(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+))))|[^\s`!()[]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

It's still completely incomprehensible though, and I'm not sure I'd trust a regex url checker that doesn't match google.com to begin with! Most languages have something built in for parsing URLs, that's a better option if possible anyway.

Comment: Yeah thanks - you're right. I was just posting this answer :)